# How to call a function that requires a value on the click of a programmatically added button in VB?

Tags: vb.net, basic

I need to call a function and return the text of the button that is added though the button is programmatically added. For example

```
AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf function(value)
```

Thought that isn't possible because of the following reason:

> Error 1   'AddressOf' operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses).

Comment: As the error message says, you have to use the name of a function (or use an anonymous method) that matches the event delegate (`sender As Object, e As EventArgs`). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I am trying to call a function that uses the text in the generated button(That could have any name) to accomplish what is in the function.

Comment: Why don't you just evaluate the according property of the passed `sender`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a lambda-expression is fine, you however have to write it correctly.  You do *not* use the AddressOf operator.  A Click event handler is a Sub, not a Function.  It requires two arguments.  So proper syntax is:

```
    AddHandler button.Click, Sub(sender, e)
                                 MessageBox.Show("Clicked!")
                                 Dim retval = SomeFunction(value)
                                 '' etc...
                             End Sub
```

VS2010 or higher required.

Comment: The only place on the entire web that says AddressOf operator is not needed! Thank you (in capitals).

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to add a tag-value to the button, which can be retrieved in the handler.